# compare dates which gives me wrong result

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I need to  compare the startDate and endDate and if  `startDate>endDate` then i need to take the starting date of the month of endDate as startDate suppose my
startDate is `"startDate": "2016-05-30T00:00:00.000Z"` endDate is `"endDate": "2016-06-05T00:00:00.000Z"` then when compare need to get `true` but i am getting false

Code:

```
 var c=(new Date(nestedObj.startDate)).getDate();
  console.log("startdate"+" "+c);
  var d=(new Date(nestedObj.endDate)).getDate();
  console.log("endtdate"+" "+d);
  console.log(c>d);
```

As you can see in the below snippet

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're only providing your result, please provide your code

Comment: @t3__rry

Please go through my updated question

Comment: Well, you are only comparing days, but the endDate is indeed larger than the startDate (is one month later)

Comment: getDate() returns day integer 1..31 hence 30 is larger then 5. You need to compare Date objects.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript#answer-493018

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript#answer-493018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var c = new Date(nestedObj.startDate)
console.log("startdate"+" "+c);
var d=new Date(nestedObj.endDate);
console.log("endtdate"+" "+d);
console.log(c>d);
```

Comment: again the same thing 

I am again getting wrong result

Comment: @Shikhathakur You are not, your start date is always earlier than the end date, look at the month.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getTime()` function rather than `getDate()`. `getTime()` return number(epoch time) that will easy to compare. Here is code that may help you

```
var c = new Date(nestedObj.startDate).getTime();
console.log("startdate " + c);
var d = new Date(nestedObj.endDate).getTime();
console.log("endtdate " + d);
console.log(c>d);
```

Even you can directly compare `Date` object as following

```
var c = new Date(nestedObj.startDate);
console.log("startdate " + c);
var d = new Date(nestedObj.endDate);
console.log("endtdate " + d);
console.log(c>d);
```

Comment: when i do typeof(c) and type(d) then i am getting a number .
so i think that should not give me false

Answer (score 1):

Why not going with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/)

Look at `moment(date1).isAfter(date2);` method.

It's easy to do all manipulation of `Date/Time`

```
if(moment(endDate).isAfter(startDate)){
//Do whatever you want
}
```